# React bootstrap modal animate only on show OR on hide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to have it so that I can go directly from one modal to another without flicker/animations for bootstrap Modals in react (using react-bootstrap), but it doesn't work because of the `fade` CSS class.

I'd like to set it so that the first modal a user opens animates, and the last one a user closes animates. So say I have 3 modals the user goes between:

```
1 => 2 => 3

Modal 1: fades in on open, no animation on close
Modal 2: no animation at all
Modal 3: no animation on open, fades out on close
```

How should I go about doing this? I've tried tinkering with the `fade` CSS class to no avail.

This feels like an anti-pattern, so maybe I don't really want to do this. What I'm trying to do is cleanly go from a Registration modal to an Account Setup modal, with it being seamless for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just reuse the same Modal component: on submit of the first and second form change the content via props and on the last form submit call the close modal method.

Comment: Yeah, that's one pattern I've considered. But it involves structuring the Login and Set Up phases so that they're in the same component, and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: This seems like a pretty low effort to me, no? Also bootstrap supoorts only one Modal at a time. I can imaging you could run into other issues while rendering one Modal right after another. I looked into the API and I'm afraid it doesn't give (at least direct) access to control the animation

Comment: Also you could look up what is happening in the css of slide and fade classes, set animation to "false" and re-implement your own behaviour like that